# ASP.NET MVC Slow Refresh on Localhost - Parallels + Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, localhost, iis-8, parallels

I have been doing my development work on a Dell running Windows 8. I switched over to Windows 10 with Parallels on a 2013 MacBook Pro 2.8 GHz 16 GB RAM. Everything is super snappy. However, when I run my project without debugging, updates are very slow. I have this exact same project running on my Dell, and I don't have the problem. Parallels is running everything super fast.

For example, I change something in my html, and when I reload, it says waiting on localhost and that first get request takes about 30 seconds before loading the page. This happens after changing a single title in my view. I have been working on this problem for about a day and have tried many things.

**What I've Tried**

- Reinstalling IIS and Deleting IIS folder in Documents
- Changing my host file at \Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts "127.0.0.1 localhost"
- Disabled IPv6
- Restarting both Virtual Machine and Mac numerous times
- De-enabling Browser Link
- List item
- Turning off Windows Defender and Firewalls

I have tried many other things, but that is what I can remember. I'm hoping someone has similar experience or can point me in the right direction.

*Side note - this project is a small-medium size web app that includes dev express controls. I did run a basic mvc project that is just a website, and it refreshed within a couple seconds when I changed the view.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the pre-alpha OS that you are running this all on?

Comment: No, I was trying to avoid that as my development environment took so long to get going, but I will get 8.1 going and give that a try, thanks.

Comment: I have the same problems running Windows 8.1. When I connect to a local database, instead of an Azure database, it is much faster. That still doesn't explain why it is so much faster on my Windows machine connected to the Azure database.

Comment: The saga continues. I tried VMWare fusion, and the problem does not occur in VMWare Fusion running Windows 10.

Comment: This describes my situation closely. Ever solve this?

Comment: @puddleglum sorry. I ended up just using VMWare Fusion even though I preferred Parallels.